# Add trailing slash to domain name

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Good afternoon!

I need add trailing slash to domain name. For example: from `http://www.domain.com` to `http://www.domain.com/`. I try to add settings to .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

but Wordpress trims trailing slash only in domain name, other addresses work fine: `http://www.domain.com/dir` - `http://www.domain.com/dir/`

Best regards, Deifinger!

Comment: `http://example.com` and `http://example.com/` are identically equivalent as far as the URL spec is concerned. Are you sure WordPress is to blame and not the browser? Why do you care anyway?

Comment: In fact, when you go to `http://example.com`, your browser sends a request with `/`.  If it doesn't show this to you, it is purely cosmetic.  I guarantee you that Wordpress isn't trimming this... it's your browser.

Comment: If you're keen on wanting a trailing slash; `echo "example.com" . "/";`

Comment: Be careful. `http://example.com` and `http://example.com/` are idenetical, but `http://example.com/abc` and `http://example.com/abc/` are not.

Comment: Quentin, you can read the importance of trailing slash [here](http://cdivilly.wordpress.com/2014/03/11/why-trailing-slashes-on-uris-are-important/)
Probably I was wrong, that WordPress trims address because I have not found facts confirming it.

Comment: Brad, maybe you right. How can I be sure that it is a cosmetic?

Comment: Fred -ii, thank you, but this is not, what I need.

Comment: @Deifinger — None of the points made by that article apply to the root of the site.

Comment: @Quentin — And what can I apply?

Comment: @Deifinger — What? That doesn't make any sense. The point is that the article doesn't say anything that is relevant to the kind of URL you are asking about.

Comment: @Quentin — If you talked about article, which I gave you in first message, I provided it for you to understand why I am concerned trailing slash

Comment: @Deifinger — Yes, and as I said, none of those points matter when it is the first slash in the path.

Comment: @Quentin — yeah, you're right.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
http://domain.com/
```

is equivalent to

```
http://domain.com
```

you cannot redirect your url from:

```
http://www.domain.com
```

to

```
http://www.domain.com/
```

Comment: How I can do this? Skype?

Comment: Now I have problem with load images and some css (404 error). And all addresses (for ex. www.example.com/faq/) redirected to home page (www.example.com)

Comment: I did some research and it seems that the browser disregards a slash after the domain. Sorry about that.